# Julia: what's the difference between map and broadcast?

Tags: julia

I have found some discussions on Julia Users group but they were too technical for me.

I would like to know what are the criteria to choose between the two.

I am following the JuliaBox tutorial but it doesn't explain much. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

`map` and `broadcast` are different when dealing with multiple collections of different dimensions. While `broadcast` will try to cast all the objects to a common dimension, `map` will directly apply the given function elementwise.

```
julia> map(+, 1, [2,2,2])
1-element Array{Int64,1}:
 3

julia> broadcast(+, 1, [2,2,2])
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 3
 3
 3
```

the broadcast example has the same result as `map(+, [1,1,1], [2,2,2])`.

Also note the behavior of `broadcast` when failing at finding a common dimension between two arguments:

```
julia> broadcast(+, [1,2,3], [2 2; 2 0])
ERROR: DimensionMismatch("arrays could not be broadcast to a common size")
Stacktrace:
 [1] _bcs1 at ./broadcast.jl:439 [inlined]
 [2] _bcs at ./broadcast.jl:433 [inlined]
 [3] broadcast_shape at ./broadcast.jl:427 [inlined]
 [4] combine_axes at ./broadcast.jl:422 [inlined]
 [5] instantiate at ./broadcast.jl:266 [inlined]
 [6] materialize at ./broadcast.jl:748 [inlined]
 [7] broadcast(::typeof(+), ::Array{Int64,1}, ::Array{Int64,2}) at ./broadcast.jl:702
 [8] top-level scope at none:0

julia> map(+, [1,2,3], [2 2; 2 0])
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 3
 4
```

Comment: Hi, there is a `5` missing at the end, I couldn't edit the answer though...  Also, this puzzles me a bit, why is `map(+, [1,2,3], [2,2,2,0])` giving me an error, while it works out in your example, where there is still a dimension mismatch and only the first three values of the array are used?

Comment: It's a very bad answer to a really good question. The equivalent of `broadcast(+, 1, [2,2,2])` would be this `map((x) -> x + 1, [2,2,2])`, and thus the comparison should be between them? Which one is better here in this case?

Answer (score 5):

Both methods apply a function to their arguments. The difference between the two is how they treat multidimensional arrays.

`map` tries to zip the arrays column first, creating an iterator of tuples, which are used as arguments to the given function. Thus

```
julia> map(+, [1,2,3,4], [10, 20, 30, 40])
4-element Array{Int64,1}:
 11
 22
 33
 44
```

while

```
julia> map(+, [1,2,3,4], [10 20; 30 40])
4-element Array{Int64,1}:
 11
 32
 23
 44
```

Notice the element pairing when changing the layout of the second array. On the other hand, `broadcast` does an element-wise application of the given function. If the two array arguments have the same dimensions, the pairing of elements is similar to `map`.

```
julia> broadcast(+, [1,2,3,4], [10, 20, 30, 40])
4-element Array{Int64,1}:
 11
 22
 33
 44
```

Otherwise, `broadcast` checks if the two arrays match in at least one dimension and that the other dimension of at least one array is equal to 1. If this condition is satisfied, `broadcast` extends the arrays to a common size by duplicating the array data along the dimension equal to 1. This is how you get

```
julia> broadcast(+, [1, 2, 3, 4], [10 20 30 40])
4×4 Array{Int64,2}:
 11  21  31  41
 12  22  32  42
 13  23  33  43
 14  24  34  44
```

Comment: For any curious readers: "`map` tries to `zip`" is literally true -- you can check its implementation. This means, for instance, `map(+, [1,2,3,4], [10 20; 30 40])` will linearize the two input arrays (b/c `zip` does), and since Julia arrays are column-major, the second array is linearized as `[10, 30, 20, 40]`. It also means that if the input arrays aren't the same length, it'll use the shorter of the two, again because `zip` does. `broadcast` is stricter + more predictable, and IMO unless you really want to linearize the input arrays, you should use it instead of `map` with multiple arrays.